# Return a boolean value if forms fails validation

Tags: javascript, function, input, boolean

I have a task:

Write a JS function that validates the content of the form - the form should have at least one mandatory numeric field and one field that simply cannot be empty. If the validation is not passed through the field, display the appropriate information to inform the user. If validation fails, the function should return false, otherwise true

So, I'm trying to return a boolean value if the from fails validation and subsequently hide the forms. I've put the boolean value into the error and success functions but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to make the check inputs function return the boolean value but it didn't work also.

I'm just trying to learn so any help regarding the best approach to this problem logically would be appreciated. I also understand that there might have been simple syntax issues, but this is also something I'm trying to get better at right now.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const num = document.getElementById('num');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

let isValid;

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
    if (isValid = true){
        form.remove;
    }
});


function checkInputs() {
    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const numValue = num.value.trim();
    const phoneValue = phone.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();
    
    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Username cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }

    if(numValue === ''){
        setErrorFor(num, 'You must have a favorite number');
        
    }else if(isNaN(numValue)){
        setErrorFor(num, 'Not a number');
    
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(num);
    }

    if(phoneValue === '+48' || phoneValue === ''){
        setErrorFor(phone, 'Phone cannot be blank');
    
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(phone);
    }
    
    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');

    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    
        setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);

    }
    
    if(passwordValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');

    }else if (passwordValue.length < 8){
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be less than 8 characters');
    
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }
    
    if(password2Value === '') {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Password cannot be blank');

    } else if(passwordValue !== password2Value) {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Passwords does not match');

    } else{
        setSuccessFor(password2);
        
    }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
    isValid = false;

}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
    isValid = true;

}
    
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}

function test(){
    if (isValid = true){
        console.log('hi')
    } else{
        console.log('HEXYU')
    }
}
```

```html
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Create Account</h2>
        </div>
        <form id="form" class="form">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your username" id="username" />
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="num">Your favorite number</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Your favorite number" id="num"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Your phone numbe" id="phone" value="+48"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email@youremail.com" id="email" />
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="passsword2">Password check</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat your password" id="password2"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <button class="form-button" >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: There might be a few things wrong here, but this line: `if (isValid = true){ form.remove;  }` - for comparisons you have to use `==` or `===` (a single `=` sets a value). Also, form.remove means nothing. What did you intend with that?

Comment: I was trying to hide the html form  by using  form.remove. Yes, you're right about the ===, but it still it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: `if (isValid) form.remove()` would permanently remove it from the DOM. If you simply want to hide it (so you could show it again later), you could do something like `if (isValid) form.setStyle('display', 'none')`

Comment: @Kinglish Thank you! I guess the entire problem was with that form.remove statement. Now that I've changed it according to your advice it did actually work. Also, is that a good practice to do it like this with the boolean values inside setError/Succes functions or is there a better way?

Comment: @AndrewMakovii, a good solution is to use `required` to check blank  which will have less if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors in your code:

1. Use `remove()` instead of remove
2. Use `==` / `===` instead of `=`

Also, you could use `required` to let user unable to submit.

`num` input type will only accept number input and `email` type input will check if there is @ in the `input`. This will save a lot of if unnecessary if statement.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const num = document.getElementById('num');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

let isValid;

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
    if (isValid = true){
        form.remove();
    }
});


function checkInputs() {
    const phoneValue = phone.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();
    

        setSuccessFor(username);
        setSuccessFor(num);
         setSuccessFor(email);
}
    if(phoneValue === '+48' ){
        setErrorFor(phone, 'Phone cannot be blank');
    }else{
        setSuccessFor(phone);
    }

    
   if (passwordValue.length < 8){
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be less than 8 characters');
    
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }
    
 if(passwordValue !== password2Value) {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Passwords does not match');

    } else{
        setSuccessFor(password2);
        
    }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
    isValid = false;

}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
    isValid = true;

}
    
 function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
function test(){
    if (isValid == true){
        console.log('hi')
    } else{
        console.log('HEXYU')
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your username" id="username" />
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="num">Your favorite number</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Your favorite number" id="num" required />
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                <input type="tel" required placeholder="Your phone numbe" id="phone" value="+48"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" required placeholder="email@youremail.com" id="email" />
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" required placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="passsword2">Password check</label>
                <input type="password" required  typeplaceholder="Repeat your password" id="password2"/>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <button class="form-button" >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```